# Applying Gradient to Text Shadow

Tags: html, css, gradient

I have some simple text, except the effect I'm trying to reach is to have a simple text shadow except the color is a gradient.

What I've tried:

```
text-shadow: 0px 0px 7px linear-gradient(90deg, #2af598 0%, #009efd 100%);
```

Is doing this even possible?

Comment: take a look at [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/2GgqR/5/)

Comment: No I meant, the color of the shadow is a gradient.

Comment: For CSS, gradients are treated as background-images, not colors.

Comment: That means this is not possible then?

Comment: Not exactly. That's more of an outline, missing the fade effect or the blur factor.

Comment: That means you can't use directly a gradient where a <color> is expected. Now, there might be a way, which would probably imply blending or compositing, but I don't know it. If it helps, it [may be done by canvas](https://jsfiddle.net/7562wy3b/) *quite* easily, but this will produce a raster image, and I guess you can also achieve this with svg, which would have the advantage of leaving text as text.

Comment: The solution in the linked questions is almost there: basically all it needs is `filter:blur`! See [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/o4gqmLy2/). @Cons7an7ine You can post that as an answer if you like.

Comment: Oh! That's pretty cool, that pretty much solves it. Thank you @MrLister.